# MSSQL 2014 Change returned Date in a different time zone

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I have a query that returns a date as one of the column however I need that date to be in a different time zone then it currently is.

```
 SELECT ISNULL(Value, 'NULL') AS VALUE, ISNULL(UPPER(FORMAT(start_date), 'MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm ')), 'NULL') as Start_Date FROM MY TABLE
```

[image]

I tried just to off set by 1 hour to make the time as in central time (currently its EST)

```
   DATEADD(hh, -1, start_date)
```

the the problem comes when the date is inside daylight saving time and all returned dates within that time fate are being offest by 1 hour
Is there a way to convert that start_date column to accommodate for it?

Comment: What you wrote doesn't change the timezone, it creates a localized string without any timezone information. SQL Server already has timezone handling functions, like [SWITCHDATEIMEOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you really care about timezones though, it would be better to use the `datetimeoffset` type.

Comment: In all SQL Server versions still in mainstream support (2016+) with both `datetime` and `datetimeoffset` you can use [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to change the timezone using a timezone name instead of the arbitrary `-1`or ambiguous `EST`. There's no standard for timezone abbreviations

Comment: You can also consider [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/07/sql-plan/at-time-zone) but please, please, please [stop using shorthand like `hh`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) - it is not much more work to type `hour`. Also [`FORMAT` is incredibly inefficient](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but); consider [one of the style numbers for convert instead](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/) (e.g. style 100 is close).

Comment: I cannot use At TIME ZONE in SQL earlier then 2016 that functionality was added into SQL server 2016 I'm working with 14

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I missed that. If you insist on using ancient versions of SQL Server you might have to use more elbow grease. See this series for example: [part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3173/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server--part-1/) | [part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3174/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server--part-2/) | [part 3](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3175/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server--part-3/)

Comment: its not my choice to use it, its my dinosaur employer. but it basically answer my question and its impossible to do it without installing some custom functionality into the server. that out of the question so basically impossible to accommodate for time zone in the earlier version of SQL thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll point out that SQL Server 2014 reached end of mainstream support on July 9th 2019.  You really shouldn't be using it in a production environment any more.

If you *must* continue using it, then you can consider using my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project.  I wrote it a long time ago, and no longer maintain it, so like your server - use at your own risk.